# Escape spaces in a linux pathname with Ruby gsub

Tags: ruby, gsub

I am trying to escape the spaces in a Linux path. However, whenever I try to escape my backslash I end up with a double slash.

Example path:

```
/mnt/drive/site/usa/1201 East/1201 East Invoice.pdf
```

So that I can use this in Linux I want to escape it as:

```
/mnt/drive/site/usa/1201\ East/1201\ East\ Invoice.pdf
```

So I'm trying this:

```
backup_item.gsub("\s", "\\\s")
```

But I get an unexpected output of

```
/mnt/drive/site/usa/1201\\ East/1201\\ East\\ Invoice.pdf
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Stefan is right; I just want to point out that if you have to escape strings for shell use you should check [`Shellwords::shellescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html):

```
require 'shellwords'

puts Shellwords.shellescape "/mnt/drive/site/usa/1201 East/1201 East Invoice.pdf"
# prints /mnt/drive/site/usa/1201\ East/1201\ East\ Invoice.pdf

# or

puts "/mnt/drive/site/usa/1201 East/1201 East Invoice.pdf".shellescape
# prints /mnt/drive/site/usa/1201\ East/1201\ East\ Invoice.pdf

# or (as reported by @hagello)
puts shellwords.escape "/mnt/drive/site/usa/1201 East/1201 East Invoice.pdf"
# prints /mnt/drive/site/usa/1201\ East/1201\ East\ Invoice.pdf
```

Comment: Or `shellwords.escape('/mnt/drive/site/usa/1201 East…')`.

Answer (score 12):

That is the string's [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-inspect) value, *"a printable version of str, surrounded by quote marks, with special characters escaped"*:

```
quoted = "path/to/file with spaces".gsub(/ /, '\ ')
=> "path/to/file\\ with\\ spaces"
```

Just print the string:

```
puts quoted
```

Output:

```
path/to/file\ with\ spaces
```

Comment: Just for anybody considering to use this solution: Shellwords also escapes special characters like `${}[]` etc.