# How to use a system call to open an image file with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

From [Escape spaces in a linux pathname with Ruby gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355597/escape-spaces-in-a-linux-pathname-with-ruby-gsub) I've tried opening an image file in Ubuntu 14.04 in ruby as below, but the space in the file name is the issue.  How do I do this without changing the file name?  I want to write a script to open multiple image files all with spaces in it.

**open_file.rb**

```
name_of_image_file = Shellwords.shellescape(name_of_image_file) 
name_of_image_file = "~/folder1/usa american_flag.jpg" 
system("gnome-open #{name_of_image_file}")
```

Comment: `Shellwords.escape` is correct here, but then you throw out the result when you assign a different (unescaped) value to `name_of_image_file`. Why?

Comment: @Jordan: I don't think `Shellwords` is the right tool for this job as it will escape the `~` and keep the shell from expanding it to the user's home directory. Best to avoid the shell entirely IMO.

Comment: @muistooshort Good point, although `File.expand_path` could be used first to avoid that issue. Edit: Oh, I see you already mentioned that in your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have things in your `name_of_image_file` that you want the shell to interpret (`'~'`) and other things in your `name_of_image_file` that you don't want the shell to interpret (`' '`).

Normally the shell will expand globing characters such as `*`, `?`, and most importantly to you, `~`. `Shellwords.shellescape` knows about all three of those so it will escape the `~`:

```
> name_of_image_file = "~/folder1/usa american_flag.jpg" 
 => "~/folder1/usa american_flag.jpg" 
> puts Shellwords.shellescape(name_of_image_file)
\~/folder1/usa\ american_flag.jpg
```

Presumably you want the shell to expand `~` to your home directory but since the `~` is escaped, that won't happen and `gnome-open` will go looking for a file called `~/folder1/usa american_flag.jpg` in the current directory.

The solution to your problem is two-fold:

1. Expand the `~` yourself using [`File.expand_path`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-expand_path).
2. Bypass the shell completely by using using the multi-argument version of [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system).

Something like this:

```
name_of_image_file = "~/folder1/usa american_flag.jpg"
system('gnome-open', File.expand_path(name_of_image_file))
```

That form of `system` doesn't invoke a shell so it doesn't matter if there are spaces (or quotes) in the filename. `File.expand_path` will expand the leading tilde for you so you don't need the shell to do it.

---

I'd go so far as to recommend that you forget that the `system(command_string)` version of `system` exists at all, you're almost always better off bypassing the shell (and all of its quoting and escaping issues) and using the `system(command, arg1, arg2, ...)` form of `system`.
Same goes for backticks, you're better off using [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) if you need to get the command's output.

Answer (score -1):

Put quotes around the he name,  use backslash to escape the quote

```
system("gnome-open \"#{name_of_image_file}\"")
```

Comment: Who expands the `~` to the current user's home directory?

Comment: This will fail if the filename has quotation marks in it.

Comment: I think you want to reverse the two lines of your code, I assumed that was a typo.  As Jordon points out this will not work if the file name has double quotes in it.